# What is the difference between Mustache.render() and Mustache.to_html()?

Tags: javascript, mustache

The [documentation](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) makes no mention of Mustache.to_html(), but every [tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/tutorial-html-templates-with-mustache-js/) for Mustache.js online uses Mustache.to_html(). Therefore I am surely missing some jewels.

Code examples would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/mustache.js), it seems **to_html** has essentially been deprecated:

```
// This is here for backwards compatibility with 0.4.x.
exports.to_html = function (template, view, partials, send) {
    var result = render(template, view, partials);

    if (typeof send === "function") {
      send(result);
    } else {
      return result;
    }
};
```

As you can see it invokes *render*.  The one difference is the extra (optional) *send* parameter, which is a callback it invokes (sending the result as a parameter).

Comment: Thank you very much. Good lesson for me is to start looking at the source code.