# Mustache Sending data back to Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, mustache

**How can I send data from my mustache template back to JQuery?**

Hello.. This is my first time using a templating library. Most of my code works fine. But at this point, I need to load data from two separate sources.

1st source is a json file, loading all the users. I have username and ids.
2nd source require userid (that I loaded in first template). I want to get data from 1st source and render it on template..at the same time, I want to send these ids to ajax and load information from 2nd source and render it on the same template.
I just have to update 1  information from 2nd source . 
How do I send this span id to ajax function? If it was a button, I could simply use onclick event with id (working). But I have to update html. What do I do?
P.S I also cant join both data in one json. The data is comming via API.

## my mustache template

```
<script id="profile-template" type="text/template">
{#users}}

     Your user id is {{id}} <br/>
     Your name is {{name}}  <br />

     Your other information <span id="{{id}}-variable-text">this data has to be loaded from other api </span>
    <button onclick="updatetext({{id}});">Update text </button>


{{/users}}
```

## My JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#spanID-from-template').html(function(){
        // ajax 
    })
}
```

I'm using following code in ajax to name and ids from first source.
this is what happening in ajax success function()

```
              var template = $("#profile-template").html();
              var html = Mustache.to_html(template, response);
              $('#users').append(html);
```

## A little hack I added to use onclick event to update text of id

Check template above and the following jquery

```
function updatetext(id){
 $("#"+id+"-variable-text").html("updated-text");

 }
```

Comment: Can you provide your `Mustache.render()` as well please?

Comment: .render() is not in jquery right?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for quick reply. My render is working perfectly.  However problem is to send userid to another javascript where I could load more data. I'll update my question in a minute

Comment: @SudharsanS I'm using mustache to_html instead of render(). And It is in Jquery.

Comment: I believe `to_html()` is deprecated in Mustache? Please include what `response` looks like.

Comment: @DanielShillcock it's working fine here. And rendering all data from first source perfectly.

Comment: It will work, but it is deprecated, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872615/what-is-the-difference-between-mustache-render-and-mustache-to-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to use a data from a rendered template, you can do the following...

The issue here is the asynchronous nature of what you are doing; rendering and calling variables from the rendered template.

```
var template = $("#profile-template").html();
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, response);
$('#users').append(html).promise().done(function(){
   $.ajax({
           url: "url here", 
           success: function(result){
              response = response.concat(result); //Do some reduction here!
              var html = Mustache.to_html(template, response); //This will only render once the promise is fulfilled
              $('#users').append(html);
           },
           error: function(x, s, e){
               console.log(e);
           }
    });
 });
```

Comment: I get your point. But Let me show you something. I can hide an element rendered with template using a button onclick event and I can also update an element.  But it require onclick event. I don't want that :( I want to use something like body onload() event but that is not working. I'll update button code in the question.

Comment: @DPlease check the Question again. I've updated my question with a little hack. However I need a little help to load data without click event.

Comment: @AhsanShabbir I've updated answer with general logic to update template without needing an `onclick`.

Comment: Thank you for your help @DanielShillcock. I really appreciate this.

Comment: My pleasure! enjoy :)